# Resize movie .m2v 576.i widescreen

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like to convert a 720x576 widescreen, interlaced .m2v movie into an interlaced mpeg file. This conversion should be uncompressed, with a 1024x576 resize to account for the widescreen.

The syntax I have set up for the command is:
`ffmpeg -i <input movie.m2v> -vf scale=w=1024:h=576 <output.mpeg>`

In this way the .mpeg file is progressive.
What command to enter to keep the interlaced file top field?

Comment: You may check the [interlace filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#interlace). However, your question looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In the first place why do you want/need 1) to resize the video, 2) to keep the interlacing?

Comment: and 3) to encode to mpeg instead of more modern codecs ?. I have found back the command I was using in the old times to convert DVD files to Xvid. There was the option `-flags +ilme+ildct` to take into account the interlacing of the input file (and keep it in the output file). However, as of today, when I have to convert a DVD I am just deinterlacing it with `-vf yadif` and encode a progressive output.